# php mysql reusable dropdown function not working with resultset

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function, foreach

I'm just trying to get a reusable dropdown function to work with information coming from either hard coded arrays and/or database results. Doesn't work correctly with any results coming from database but works perfect if I hard code an associative array like below. The output for any database result shows the amount of table columns as the number of options and only displays information from the first row like below:

```
  <option value=Answer_Id>1</option>
  <option value=Answer_Name>Poor</option>
```

What am I missing?

***Dropdown***

```
  function dropdown_options($name, $selected, $options){
    $html = "<select id=" . $name . " name=" . $name . ">";
    $html .= "<option value=''> - Select - </option>";
    foreach($options as $value=>$option){
      if($selected == $value){
        $html .= "<option value=" . $value . " selected='selected'>".$option."</option>";
      }else{
        $html .= "<option value=" . $value . ">".$option."</option>";
      }
    }
    $html .= '</select>';
    return $html;
  }
```

***Calling Function***

Either interchangeable associative arrays work perfect

```
  $answer = array ("1"=>"Poor","2"=>"Meh","3"=>"Average","4"=>"Good","5"=>"Awesome");
  echo $common->dropdown_options($dropdown, $blog_status, $answer);
```

Using a database function

```
  $status = $database->check_security_exists();
  echo $common->dropdown_options($dropdown, $blog_security, $status->fetch_assoc());
```

Comment: what the output which you got for the $status->fetch_assoc();

Comment: post output of `print_r($status->fetch_assoc());`